# How to change the colour on the image?

Tags: javascript

If I click on the image it should be changed the color of the part of the image.Then I want to replace the image.Can it be done using javasript?
Pls help me.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript can't change physical images like .jpg, .png or .gif (to my knowledge) But replacing images is easy.

```
document.getElementById("foo").src = "example.jpg";
```

Comment: Unless you need to programmatically change the colour to a value determined at runtime that could have many options - just create several images for each colour and swap in the appropriately-coloured one using the Javascript above.

If you preload the images via JS the change should appear to be instant.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean changing the color of the clicked pixel, not, this is not possible with JavaScript only. But you can get the coordinates and pass them to a PHP script. In PHP you can change the image.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I try to do using this code.

if(imagecopy  ( Aseat.png , seat_new.png  , 0  , 1  , 0  , 1  , 10  , 16  ))){
 return Aseat.png;
 
 header("Location:Test1.html");
imagegif(Aseat.png);

imagedestroy(Aseat.png);
imagedestroy(seat_new.png);
}

But I get error like this.

Parse error: parse error in D:\xampp\htdocs\seat_planner\Testimage.php on line 20

Line 20 of above code is
if(imagecopy  ( Aseat.png , seat_new.png  , 0  , 1  , 0  , 1  , 10  , 16  ))){

pls give me an instruction.

Comment: You have to put all your strings into quotes. "Aseat.png", "seat_new.png" etc.

Answer (score 0):

Unless i misunderstood i think you could probably place a transparent image above the image you wanted to change, thereby kind of changing the appearance of the image. I think i did something like this with [prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/) once.

Answer (score 0):

As for the color change, yes it can be done, you could probably cook something with SVG and the Canvas element and JavaScript using your image.

Comment: I don't know about SVG and Canvas element.Pls tell me how can I use these for my propose.Actually I want to change the colour of the part of the image when click the mouse on that part.